# AWS - EC2 instances not showing up in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am trying to set up mongodb on and EC2 instance configured for EBS. I am following this [MongoDB walkthrough](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/). I created a new instance with the ec2 command line tool:

```
ec2-run-instances ami-05355a6c -t m1.large -b "/dev/xvdf=:200:false:io1:1000" -b "/dev/xvdg=:25:false:io1:250" -b "/dev/xvdh=:10:false:io1:100" --ebs-optimized true
```

and it says the instance is created. However, when I go to the aws console, it doesn't show up. Additionally, when I run:

```
ec2-describe-instances [instance id]
```

it prints out info for a running instance

```
RESERVATION r-5c259387c 6724431926739   
INSTANCE    [instance-id]   ami-05355a6c    ec2-[ip-address].computer-1.amazonaws.com   ip-172-31-41-121.ec2.internal   running     0       m1.large    2015-11-06T03:18:26+0000    us-east-1c  aki-88aarjns8           monitoring-disabled [ip-address]    [internal-ip-address]   vpc-778e98sy    subnet-3060eb47 ebs                 paravirtual xen     sg-d94097bd default true    
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/sda1   vol-beb6posj    2015-11-06T03:18:30.000Z    true        
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/xvdf   vol-e2b75aef    2015-11-06T03:18:30.000Z    false       
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/xvdg   vol-29b65ard    2015-11-06T03:18:30.000Z    false       
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/xvdh   vol-bfb65sdf    2015-11-06T03:18:30.000Z    false       
NIC eni-20sdff6d    subnet-3060eb47 vpc-778ee212    672443198021    in-use  [internal-ip-address]   true
NICATTACHMENT   eni-attach-c916sdfe 0   attached    2015-11-05T20:18:26-0700    true
NICASSOCIATION  [ip-address]    amazon  [internal-ip-address]
GROUP   sg-dd4577bd default
PRIVATEIPADDRESS    [ip-address]    [internal-ip-address]
```

What am I missing? Where is this instance being created? Why does it not show up in my list of instances?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but make sure you're specifying the correct region that the instance in located in.

Comment: That AMI seems to be in Virginia. Check your region on the Management Console, make sure it is in Virginia. Another thing to verify is if you are really using the same account on the CLI and the Management Console.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to select the region you want to view in the aws console. You have created instances in region A and your console is displaying instances of region B. Select the region from the top right corner option to the left of 'support' option

Comment: thank you.  also, it's pretty incredible that the default is not to show everything, let alone that there is no option to show everything.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasted 4 hours just to figure out this.

Comment: Heh. Just did this myself and thankfully found this answer before I lost a load of time!

Comment: Lost hours until found your answer. Thanks !